# enableWriteAheadLogging() in greenDAO

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, greendao

Do I need to call enableWriteAheadLogging() on the database before creating a DaoMaster? Is this helpful when multithreading or does DaoMaster handle this automatically? I need non-blocking reads from multiple threads.

Comment: Why do you think you need WAL for concurrent reads?

Comment: @CL. Because some threads write.

Comment: If the database format is SQLite then that supports multiple concurrent readers but only a single writer, and when writing the database is locked -- http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5

Comment: See the second advantage of [WAL](http://sqlite.org/wal.html). The intention is to read **and** write simultaniously.

Answer (score 0):

It (`enableWriteAheadLogging ()`) doesn't get called somewhere in greendao, so you have to call it yourself, i.e. in your implementation of OpenHelper.

Greendao uses transactions though. There is also some synchronization done inside greendao, but to be sure you should use `enableWriteAheadLogging ()`.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#enableWriteAheadLogging()

`DatabaseOpenHelper.getWritableDb()` returns a `SQLiteDatabase` under the hood so you could cast to this and call `enableWriteAheadLogging` (Note writers should use `beginTransactionNonExclusive`)

Unfortunately, for my purposes, the `DatabaseOpenHelper.getEncryptedWritableDb()` returns a `sqlcipher.SQLiteDatabase` which does not expose this functionality